# Proposal for a new [leniency] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be a common theme among some questions, where an instructor is unsure whether course policy should be strictly applied.  I'd like to suggest the creation of a [leniency](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leniency) tag.  The tag summary would say:

> Seeking advice about whether policy should be strictly applied, or whether exceptions should be made for special cases

Examples of questions where such a tag could apply:

- [How do I appropriately penalize late projects?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3664/22223)

  Currently tagged: [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading)
- [Exam exceptions for student with disabilities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13822/22223)

  Currently tagged: [professors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professors) [ethics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability)
- [Is "no late work" a common policy?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18513/22223)

  Currently tagged: [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading)
- [How to deal with students who lose their digital work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29776/22223)

  Currently tagged: [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) [homework](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)
- [Is this a legitimate excuse for missing an exam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56210/22223)

  Currently tagged: [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)
- [How many excuses are too many?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55885/22223)

  Currently tagged: [policy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy)
- [Dealing with late assignments as a teacher assistant](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58887/22223)

  Currently tagged: [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading) [homework](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)
- [In case of in-lecture quizzes, is it unreasonable to fail students who are late or absent?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/64025/22223)

  Currently tagged: [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) [undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate) [attendance](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attendance)
- [Students trying to negotiate away penalties for late submission of coursework](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/80670/22223)

  Currently tagged: [students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/students) [deadlines](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadlines) [homework](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)
- [Am I being a "mean" instructor, denying an extension on a take home exam](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/80951/22223)

  Currently tagged: [ethics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) [students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/students) [community-college](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-college)

There would be significant overlap with [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching), but I think that the questions above all relate to a specific teaching concern, enough to warrant the creation of a tag.

Comment: Please see related question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361833/umbrella-term-for-penalty-and-bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a tag covering this general topic of questions is a good idea since finding other questions on this issue is very difficult due to the lack of a common keyword.

However, I would expand the scope slightly to also cover penalties, since a large portion of questions dealing with leniency are naturally about penalties already. Moreover, a leniency towards one student can be often interpreted as a penalty for the other students. So a question tagged *leniency* may be a duplicate of one that only considers penalties.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a good umbrella term to cover both cases (but [I am looking for one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/361833/42471)). Either way, whatever the outcome, [leniency](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leniency) and [penalties](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penalties) should be synonymised to the main tag.

Comment: Are there examples of questions about penalties where "leniency" fails to describe the topic?

Comment: @200_success: Depends on how exactly you define *describe the topic:* In some sense, any leniency is the absence of a penalty, and any penalty is the absence of leniency. But I do not think that the word *leniency* would be amongst the first to come to anybody’s mind when somebody would ask a question along the lines of: “A student did X during the exam, what is an appropriate penalty?”

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [policy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy) tag for this class of question?

> On the formulation and application of formal rules and regulations by a university, instructor, or publisher.

We can also make words like "leniency" "penalties" and "punishment"  into tag synonyms.

Comment: At least to me, *policy* implies that you a predefine a standard on how to deal with a given situation. However, at least some of the questions in question are about exceptional cases that have to be dealt with without such a standard. This does not mean that I am against having all these questions under one umbrella, but *policy* does not seem to be the perfect name – though it may still be the best that exists.

Comment: *Policy* could refer to policies about encouraging and supporting diversity, sexual harassment, sexual conduct between a student and a teaching assistant, plagiarism, lab safety, leave of absence, etc., etc.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, and all of those policies can be applied with some degree of _leniency_ or _strictness_. Which is why it seems reasonable to me to keep it all under [tag:policy]. (Other tags on the question, like [tag:grading], [tag:sexual-misconduct], [tag:cheating], can help distinguish between policies in different domains.)