# Should we have a tag for degree revocation questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Related : [Should we have a canonical question about degree revocations?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/should-we-have-a-canonical-question-about-degree-revocations)

Considering the high number of questions on whether, how, and when degrees can be revoked, would it be helpful to have a [degree-revocation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degree-revocation) tag? This could help with tracking how many degree revocation questions we have, with identifying potential duplicate targets, and guiding question askers who might have a similar question.

Comment: I cannot find a FAQ about how to request a new tag, but I think https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/proposal-for-a-new-leniency-tag is a really nice format ...